# appendBuffer() not appending into sourceBuffer

Tags: javascript, stream, fetch, buffer, media-source

I am fetching `fetch()` a video from an API.

The `response.body` is a readableStream. So I read it into `reader`.

All the chunks (`value`) are then pushed into an array of chunks (`chunks.push(value)`).

The array of chunks is then transformed into an arrayBuffer (`let buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()`) since blob can not be appended to sourceBuffer.

All the steps above work correctly! My only issue is to append the buffer into the sourceBuffer (`sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer)`).

The console pops no error but the sourceBuffer is not updated. It keeps empty.

Does someone have an idea, what is going on?

Thanks a lot

```
<body>
<video id="test-video-api">
</video>
<script>

    const fetchUrl = "https://myserver/api/video?fuid=12345";
    const videoTag = document.getElementById("test-video-api");

    function getVideo(){
        if (window.MediaSource) {
            var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
            videoTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
            mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
        } else {
            console.log("The Media Source Extensions API is not supported.")
        }

        async function sourceOpen(e) {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(videoTag.src);
            const mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2"; profiles="isom,iso2,avc1,mp41"';
            var mediaSource = e.target;
            var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
            let chunks = [];
            let response = await fetch(fetchUrl, {method: "GET", credentials: "include"});
            const reader = response.body.getReader();
            while (true){
                const {done, value} = await reader.read();
                chunks.push(value);
                if(done){
                    let blob = new Blob(chunks);
                    let buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getVideo()

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd run the page and check `chrome://media-internals/` for any suspicious logs/errors

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to wait for the buffer to finish updating

Also chunks.push(value); after if (done)

```
    while (true) {
        const {done, value} = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            let blob = new Blob(chunks);
            let buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
            while (true) {
                if (!sourceBuffer.updating) break
                console.log('bufferupdating, so wait...')
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
            }
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
            while (true) {
                if (!sourceBuffer.updating) break
                console.log('buffer updating, so wait...')
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
            }
            break
        }
        chunks.push(value);
        total += value.length;
        console.log(total)
    }
```